# How do I permanently change the console TTY font type so it holds after reboot?

Tags: command-line, console, tty, fonts

I'm running Ubuntu 15.04 64-bit Desktop Edition (A Debian based Linux).

I used `sudo dpkg-reconfigure console-setup` from the command line to change the default console font type to Terminus.  Immediately afterwards the console fonts changed to the sharper looking font face.

However, after a reboot <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> takes me to a console window that has the original chunkier looking style font face, not my selected choice.

The `/etc/default/console-setup` file appears to have been changed to my choices.

```
# CONFIGURATION FILE FOR SETUPCON

# Consult the console-setup(5) manual page.

ACTIVE_CONSOLES="/dev/tty[1-6]"

CHARMAP="UTF-8"

CODESET="guess"
FONTFACE="Terminus"
FONTSIZE="8x16"

VIDEOMODE=

# The following is an example how to use a braille font
# FONT='lat9w-08.psf.gz brl-8x8.psf'
```

How do I permanently change the console font to use my preferred font?

Comment: This answer on askuntu may help you: http://askubuntu.com/a/396254/399775

Comment: So it appears that it's a known bug.  Unfortunately in the askubuntu question the answer suggested is to create an upstart script.  Ubuntu 15.04 and Debian have now adopted systemd and no longer use upstart.

Answer (score 8):

See https://askubuntu.com/questions/630118/ and https://askubuntu.com/questions/328463/.

This problem seems to be caused by a mismatch in the naming of fonts
that console-setup expects vs what are in `/usr/share/consolefonts/`, and
thus copied to `/etc/console-setup/` when you pick a font to use (using
`dpkg-reconfigure console-setup`).

If you go to a console and do an `strace /lib/udev/console-setup-tty fbcon`,
you can see that it is trying to open fonts like this:

```
/etc/console-setup/Lat15-TerminusBold11x22.psf
```

But if you look in `/etc/console-setup/`, there are only a handful of
fonts in there (the ones you picked), and they look more like this:

```
/etc/console-setup/Lat15-TerminusBold22x11.psf.gz
```

One has height x width, and the other has width x height.

The problem can be fixed in a few ways.

(1) `/lib/udev/console-setup-tty` could be fixed - This is the more
permanent, upstream solution.

(2) You could manually change `/etc/default/console-setup`, reversing the
height and width in FONTSIZE.  This will need to be done each time you
change the fonts using `dpkg-reconfigure console-setup`.  But when the
machine reboots, that preference is kept.

(3) You could install the fonts that console-setup-tty expects.  This
is what I call the "overkill" option.  I did it like this:

In /etc/rc.local:

```
# install console fonts and then set up console
/etc/console-setup/fonts.sh install
/lib/udev/console-setup-tty fbcon
```

Create a script called `/etc/console-setup/fonts.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

action=$1

srcdir="/usr/share/consolefonts"
parent="/etc/console-setup"
subdir="fonts"

case "$1" in
    install)
        # console fonts are not named properly in Ubuntu 15.04, compensate
        [[ -d $parent/$subdir ]] || mkdir $parent/$subdir
        for x in $( cd $srcdir ; ls -1 ) ; do
           # rearrange the two numbers from HHxWW to WWxHH
           y=$(echo "$x" | sed -e 's/^\([^-]*\)-\([^0-9]*\)\([0-9]*\)x\([0-9]*\).psf.gz/\1-\2\4x\3.psf.gz/g')
           # whether the pattern above matches or not, we'll be uncompressing here
           z=${y/.psf.gz/.psf}
           [[ ! -f $parent/$subdir/$z ]] && zcat $srcdir/$x > $parent/$subdir/$z
           [[ ! -L $parent/$z ]] && ln -sv $subdir/$z $parent/$z
        done
        ;;
    uninstall)
        rm -rf $parent/$subdir
        # only remove broken links (links to the fonts we removed above)
        rm $(find -L $parent -type l)
        ;;
    *)
        echo "$(basename $0) install|uninstall"
        ;;
esac

exit 0
```

For a quick pragmatic solution, I'd do #2, with a comment in the file that
it may be need to be re-done if you choose a different font (assuming the
comment does not also get overwritten).

But #3 works well with minimal fuss or mess.

Comment: I can confirm five years later that this has been fixed in (1). :)

Answer (score 7):

I've recently encountered this problem on my Ubuntu 15.04 64 bit box. The `setupcon` command set the fonts to what I had set with `dpkg-reconfigure console-setup`.

I added `setupcon` to my rc.local, but that left a gap where the font was still wrong (because rc.local is executed after the console is setup), so that wasn't good enough for me.

So, I decided to go deeper. I edited my `/lib/systemd/system/console-setup.service` file and appended `ExecStart=/bin/setupcon` to the end of the file. That will call `setupcon` when the console is setup, correcting the fonts on boot *without* a time gap.

Answer (score 4):

The simplest solution I found was to edit `/etc/default/console-setup` to set

```
FONT="Lat7-Terminus32x16.psf.gz"
```

and comment out everything else except the `ACTIVE_CONSOLES` line.

You can apply this immediately with `setupcon`, and it will be applied after rebooting as well.

Specifying the font name rather than the individual components works around the naming mismatch described by Alan Porter.

Comment: BTW on OpenSUSE you might have to install `console-setup` first.